# Species ID from Hungary

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

[image]

I found it on the wall, it was calm for 15 minutes. Central Europe, Hungary. Never seen anything like this. I have two more pictures.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a *[Gastropacha Quercifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastropacha_quercifolia)*, the Lappet Moth.

[image: Gastropacha quercifolia]

> > It is found in Europe and Northern and Eastern Asia.
> >
> > The wingspan is 50–90 mm. The females are larger than the males. The moth flies from June to July depending on the location. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastropacha_quercifolia)